# I am building a bubble chart in AM-Charts but facing issues in plotting String values on X-axis

Tags: charts, amcharts

I am new to AM-charts, I am building a bubble chart in AM-charts http://www.amcharts.com/demos/bubble-chart/.

I want to plot following data in bubble chart where name should be appear on X-axis and job should be on Y-axis.

```
[{"name":"abc","jobs":15, "value":63500},{{"name":"pqr","jobs":15, "value":33000}}]
```

My bubble chart configuration is as follows-

```
{
    "type": "xy",
    "theme": "light",
    "titles": [
        {
            "text": title,
            "size": 16
        }
    ],
    "balloon": {
        "fixedPosition": true,

    },
    "dataProvider": [{"name":"abc","job":15, "value":63500},{{"name":"pqr","job":15, "value":33000}}],
    "valueAxes": [
        {
            "position": "bottom",
            "axisAlpha": 0
        },
        {
            "minMaxMultiplier": 1.2,
            "axisAlpha": 0,
            "position": "left"
        }
    ],
    "startDuration": 1.5,
    "graphs": [
        {
            "balloonText": "Name: <b>[[name]]</b> Jobs: <b>[[job]]</b><br>value: <b>[[value]]</b>",
            "bullet": "round",
            "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.2,
            "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
            "lineAlpha": 0,
            "fillAlphas": 0,
            "valueField": "value",
            "xField": "name",
            "yField": "job",
            "maxBulletSize": 50,
            "minBulletSize": 20
        }
    ],
    "marginLeft": 46,
    "marginBottom": 35,
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "chartScrollbar": {
        "offset": 15,
        "scrollbarHeight": 5
    }
}
```

I am not able to see bubble chart with this configuration. No error or warning in console.

Can anyone please suggest me some solution to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a syntax error in your `dataProvider`. The second object has double curly brackets.

Comment: But it's still not working because you use strings for the `xField`. I'm not 100% sure, but I think XY-Charts don't support categorys on the x-axis.

Comment: XY chart does not support string-based categories. Both of the axis on XY chart are numeric (or date). Is there a specific reason you want to use XY, not a regular Serial chart for this?

Comment: Thanks Gerric and Martyn

Comment: I want add Stock category on x axis and Number of that stock category traded on y axis. And the Volume or value in bubble.  Is that possible?